# How to Compare Last two modified files using powershell compare-object

Tags: powershell

i have a powershell script to compare two files as per user selection, but i want to compare last two modified files without asking user input

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
cd\
cd .\script
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Available Files "
Write-Host "================="
Get-ChildItem | Format-table -Property Name -HideTableHeaders
$file = 'c:\script\mismatchfound.txt'
$ref = get-content (Read-Host "Enter Reference FileName")
$dif = get-content (Read-Host "Enter Difference FileName")
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref  -DifferenceObject $dif  -CaseSensitive | Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize | out-file $file -Width 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of write-Error you can use write-host, this will work in all version of powershell

```
cd\
cd .\Scripts
$File = 'c:\script\mismatchfound.txt'
$CompareFiles = Get-ChildItem -File  | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object  -Last 2
If ($Files.count -eq 2) {
    $Ref = get-content ($CompareFiles[0])
    $Dif = get-content ($CompareFiles[1])

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref  -DifferenceObject $dif  -CaseSensitive | Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize | out-file $file -Width 200 
} Else {
    Write-Host "File missing " -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: This one works fine, thank you for the time and answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

```
$FilePath = '.\path\to\your\files'
$File = 'c:\script\mismatchfound.txt'
$CompareFiles = Get-ChildItem $FilePath -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 2

If ($Files.count -eq 2) {
    $Ref = get-content $CompareFiles[0]
    $Dif = get-content $CompareFiles[1]

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref  -DifferenceObject $dif  -CaseSensitive | Format-table InputObject, SideIndicator -Autosize | out-file $file -Width 200 
}
Else{
    Write-Error '2 files not returned.'
}
```

This uses `Get-ChildItem` to return only files from the path you specify in `$FilePath`. It then uses `Sort-Object` to sort them by the `LastWriteTime` attribute of the files. Then it uses `Select-Object` to filter for just the last two objects returned in that collection.

Then we use a `if` to validate that we have two files and if we do, then put them in the `$Ref` and `$Dif` variables and use `Compare-Object` per your code.

If two files aren't returned, we return an error.

Comment: thanks for the time, the above script displays error, i think we have to add this    $Ref=get-content ($CompareFiles[0]) , i edited your answer and added the same